# Rails role based authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, role-based

Does http://code.google.com/p/rolerequirement/ Role requirement works with Rails 3? If not, where can I find a role based management plugin like this for Rails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

Check out the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan).

Answer (score 1):

Try canard https://rubygems.org/gems/canard brings roles to the beautifully simple cancan.

Answer (score 0):

Some people use Acl9 as well.

https://github.com/be9/acl9